# I'm having an issue reusing includes for EF 5. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm having an issue with the following code.

```
public IEnumerable<BillingConfiguration> GetBillingConfigurationsForAccount(int accountId, DateTime? effectiveDate)
    {
        var result = new List<BillingConfiguration>();
        var accountIds = new List<int>();
        var billingGroupIds = new List<int>();

        using (var context = new GbContext())
        {
            var account = context.Accounts.Where(a => a.AccountId == accountId).SingleOrDefault();
            if (account.ParentAccountId == null) // This is a parent account
            {
                // Get list of sub account ids
                accountIds = context.Accounts.Where(a => a.ParentAccountId == accountId).Select(x => x.AccountId).ToList();
                accountIds.Add(accountId);
            }
            else // This is a sub account
            {
                accountIds.Add(accountId);
            }

            // Get list of Billing Configurations for all accountIds
            IQueryable<BillingConfigurationAccount> accountQuery = context.BillingConfigurationAccounts
                .Where(a => accountIds.Contains(a.AccountId)).AsQueryable();
            AddBillingConfigurationAccountIncludes(accountQuery);
            var accountBillingConfigurations = accountQuery.ToList();

            //IQueryable<BillingConfigurationAccount> accountQuery = context.BillingConfigurationAccounts;
            //AddBillingConfigurationAccountIncludes(accountQuery);
            //accountQuery = accountQuery.Where(a => accountIds.Contains(a.AccountId));
            //var accountBillingConfigurations = accountQuery.ToList();   

            if (accountBillingConfigurations.HasValues())
            {
                accountBillingConfigurations.ForEach(x => result.Add(x.BillingConfiguration));
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
private void AddBillingConfigurationAccountIncludes(IQueryable<BillingConfigurationAccount> query)
    {
        query = query
            .Include(p => p.BillingConfiguration)
            .Include(p => p.BillingConfiguration.BillingConfigurationLevel)
            .Include(p => p.BillingConfiguration.BillType)
            .Include(p => p.BillingConfiguration.PayerOptionType)
            .Include(p => p.BillingConfiguration.BillModeOptions)
            .Include(p => p.BillingConfiguration.BillModeOptions.Select(m => m.BillMode))
            .Include(p => p.BillingConfiguration.BillModeOptions.Select(m => m.FirstPastDueDateOptionsType))
            .Include(p => p.BillingConfiguration.BillModeOptions.Select(m => m.LapseNoticeOptionsType))
            .Include(p => p.BillingConfiguration.BillModeOptions.Select(m => m.PaymentDueDateOptionsType))
            .Include(p => p.BillingConfiguration.BillModeOptions.Select(m => m.PaymentGracePeriodType))
            .Include(p => p.BillingConfiguration.BillModeOptions.Select(m => m.SecondPastDueDateOptionsType))
            .Include(p => p.BillingConfiguration.BillModeOptions.Select(m => m.BillModeOptionPaymentMethods))
            .Include(p => p.BillingConfiguration.BillModeOptions.Select(m => m.BillModeOptionPaymentMethods.Select(n => n.PaymentMethodType)));
    }
```

When I look at the `accountBillingConfigurations` it has 2 items in the list, however the `BillingConfiguration` entity is null, the `BillingConfigurationId` is there and correct, but its not bringing back the `BillingConfiguration` entity.

Now if I do everything inline like this it works as expected. The where clause and the includes are identical.

```
public IEnumerable<BillingConfiguration> GetBillingConfigurationsForAccount(int accountId, DateTime? effectiveDate)
    {
        var result = new List<BillingConfiguration>();
        var accountIds = new List<int>();
        var billingGroupIds = new List<int>();

        using (var context = new GbContext())
        {
            var account = context.Accounts.Where(a => a.AccountId == accountId).SingleOrDefault();
            if (account.ParentAccountId == null) // This is a parent account
            {
                // Get list of sub account ids
                accountIds = context.Accounts.Where(a => a.ParentAccountId == accountId).Select(x => x.AccountId).ToList();
                accountIds.Add(accountId);
            }
            else // This is a sub account
            {
                accountIds.Add(accountId);
            }

            // Get list of Billing Configurations for all accountIds
            var accountBillingConfigurations = context.BillingConfigurationAccounts
                .Include(p => p.BillingConfiguration)
                .Include(p => p.BillingConfiguration.BillingConfigurationLevel)
                .Include(p => p.BillingConfiguration.BillType)
                .Include(p => p.BillingConfiguration.PayerOptionType)
                .Include(p => p.BillingConfiguration.BillModeOptions)
                .Include(p => p.BillingConfiguration.BillModeOptions.Select(m => m.BillMode))
                .Include(p => p.BillingConfiguration.BillModeOptions.Select(m => m.FirstPastDueDateOptionsType))
                .Include(p => p.BillingConfiguration.BillModeOptions.Select(m => m.LapseNoticeOptionsType))
                .Include(p => p.BillingConfiguration.BillModeOptions.Select(m => m.PaymentDueDateOptionsType))
                .Include(p => p.BillingConfiguration.BillModeOptions.Select(m => m.PaymentGracePeriodType))
                .Include(p => p.BillingConfiguration.BillModeOptions.Select(m => m.SecondPastDueDateOptionsType))
                .Include(p => p.BillingConfiguration.BillModeOptions.Select(m => m.BillModeOptionPaymentMethods))
                .Include(p => p.BillingConfiguration.BillModeOptions.Select(m => m.BillModeOptionPaymentMethods.Select(n => n.PaymentMethodType)))
                .Where(a => accountIds.Contains(a.AccountId));

            if (accountBillingConfigurations.HasValues())
            {
                accountBillingConfigurations.ForEach(x => result.Add(x.BillingConfiguration));
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

That code actually fills out the `BillingConfiguration` entity and all its sub entities. 
Is what I'm trying to do possible? and if, so what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a subtle one.

You correctly assume that a method like

```
void SomeMethod(IQueryable<T> query)
```

can modify the *reference* object it receives and that these modifications will be visible outside the scope of the method.

However... the method doesn't modify the object, it *replaces* it. The assignment `=` assigns the return value of the `Include` method to the `query` variable. Now *inside* the method, the previous `query` variable is out of scope, because the reference is overwritten by a reference to the new object. But *outside* the method this new reference will never be known. There the old reference still applies.

The remedy is simple: return the new reference:

```
IQueryable<T> SomeMethod(IQueryable<T> query)
```

In you case this would become:

```
accountQuery = AddBillingConfigurationAccountIncludes(accountQuery);
```

If you don't believe me, try this little program in Linqpad :)

```
void Main()
{
    var ints = Enumerable.Range(1,10).ToArray();
    AddInt(ints, 11);
    ints.Dump();
}

void AddInt(IEnumerable<int> list, int i)
{
    list = list.Concat(new[] {i});
    list.Dump();
}
```